# What does "protection boundaries" mean?

Tags: multithreading, memory-address

I just read a text about threads that says "address space does not need protection boundaries" and I was wondering what protection boundaries mean on this context.

Comment: What was the text, what is its title and about what it was written?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably referring to [Memory Protection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366785(v=vs.85).aspx). This relates to threading because separate threads may overwrite each other when trying to access the same memory space.

Comment: Yes, I have been reading about thread synchronization to avoid many threads trying to access the same resource at the same time, but what would "boundaries" mean on this case? That is what I am not sure about.